# Llamar función JS desde HTML

Tags: javascript, html, funciones

el código es el siguiente:

```js
function generaTabla(stringDatos) {

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
    var filaActual = stringDatos.split(';');
    var datoActual = filaActual.split(',')
    // Obtener la referencia del elemento body
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    // Crea un elemento <table> y un elemento <tbody>
    var tabla   = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    // Crea las celdas
    for (var i = 0; i < filaActual; i++) {
    // Crea las fila de la tabla
    var fila = document.createElement("tr");

    for (var j = 0; j < filaActual.length; j++) {
      // Crea un elemento <td> y un nodo de texto, haz que el nodo de
      // texto sea el contenido de <td>, ubica el elemento <td> al final
      // de la fila de la tabla
      var celda = document.createElement("td");
      var textoCelda = document.createTextNode(filaActual[i]);
      celda.appendChild(textoCelda);
      fila.appendChild(celda);
    }

    // agrega la fila al final de la tabla (al final del elemento tblbody)
    tblBody.appendChild(fila);
    }
```

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Muestra de datos{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<script>src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/scripts.js')}}"</script>
<div class="primary">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Muestra de datos</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <h3>Muestra de los datos:</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="myDinamicTable">
        <p>Aquí va la tabla</p>
        <input type = "button" onclick = "generaTabla(stringDatos)" value = "Display">
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

El tema es que cuando clicko el botón no realiza ninguna acción. Lo que pretendo es que con un string que llega del back, mediante el código de js que crea la tabla se muestre en el html en cuestión. No se si lo estoy llamando incorrectamente o cuál es el problema pero poniendo la tabla yo directamente en el html si la captaba(sin el formato deseado claro) osea que el string le está llegando. Alguién me da un poco de luz?

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo!

Comment: ¿donde defines `stringDatos`?  Es decir, lo usas como parámetro en el `onclick` pero no veo que le digas lo que es en ningun momento previo

Comment: El stringdatos se lo paso por el main.py, en el template en cuestión le paso el array resultado de ejecutar una función de parseo de datos. El caso es que si yo lo hago directamente poniendo for valor un stringDatos si me muestra los datos por pantalla.

Comment: mmm... no se que tipo de template estas usando, pero el `stringDatos` dentro del `onclick` no parece una variable de sustitución que se reemplace al generar el HTML.  De todas formas, si lo fuera, quizas es que debe ir entre comillas (o apóstrofes) si se trata de un string, por lo tanto seria así:  `onclick = "generaTabla('stringDatos')" `